# Calculate period doubling bifurcation points

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, mathematica, bifurcation

For a given logistic family $f_{\mu}(x)= \mu*x*(1-x),$ where $\mu \in [0, 4]$ and $x \in [0,1].$ This family undergoes the period doubling bifurcation. Let $\mu_{n}$ denote the value of $\mu$ where a $2^n$-cycle first appears. It is quite difficult to calculate $\mu_{n}$ for large $n$. Can someone please tell me how the values of $\mu_{n}$ will be evaluated by Matlab or Mathematica.
P.S.: If anyone has a Code/program to calculate "Bifurcation points", please provide the same.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/DynamicalSystems/Bifurcation.nb  or at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/mathematica-code-for-bifurcation-diagram

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't find the exact values of $\mu_n$ from the bifurcation diagram. My goal is to find/calculate the values of $\mu_n.$

Answer (score 2):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script to plot the bifurcations.

```
Logistic = Compile[{{\[Mu], _Real}}, ({\[Mu], #} &) /@Union[Drop[NestList[\[Mu] # (1 - #) &, .2, 300], 100]]];
f = Table[Logistic[\[Mu]], {\[Mu], 0, 4, .0006}];
ListPlot[Flatten[f, 1], PlotStyle -> {Black,Opacity[0.02], AbsolutePointSize[.001]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't find the exact values of $\mu_{n}$ from the bifurcation diagram. My goal is to find/calculate the values of $\mu_{n}$.

Comment: Please. Have a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html